# Migrate existing Artifactory OSS installation to existing Artifactory PRO installation

Tags: artifactory

I tried setting up a remote-repo on my PRO installation to replicate from the OSS installation but I get an error.

> Error testing pull replication config: Replication to remote
>   open-source Artifactory instance is not supported.

Is there a script that can use the CLI to download each OSS artifact and upload to the PRO installation?
Or, do I need to purchase a PRO license, export the OSS version, and import into a new PRO installation, just to be able to replicate from one instance to the other?

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to follow [these instructions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingfromOSStoPro) from the JFrog wiki.
Note that if you've already installed your new Pro and started uploading Artifacts to it, you might need to run an Export on each repo, do a "clean upgrade" as per the link, and import the repos data back in. Do not do a full export on your pro, as the import will override the OSS data you upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading all the artifacts from the OSS artifactory (20GB) and wrote a simple script using jfrog cli to upload the files to the PRO artifactory. No down time, and didn't have to modify a working server just to be compatible for replication.

Answer (score 0):

There is [this (new) Wiki page](https://jfrog.com/download-jfrog-platform/) that talks about updating OSS to Pro in place. I couldn't make it to work, the license would not apply properly, and the start-up kept failing. I also didn't exactly want to do an "in-place" update, and instead tried to run Pro version on a separate system against a copy of the OSS data.

The remaining method (barring manually re-importing all artifacts as @Branson did) is full import export. There doesn't seem to be clear instructions on how to do this (anymore), the ["Upgrading Artifactory" wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingfromOSStoPro) doesn't anymore talk about migrating between installation types. It looks like there was a section for this there before, judging by the URL fragment in the OP's URL, but it's no longer there.

Having just completed this myself, this is the process that I followed. Note that in my case, the Pro version runs on another system.

1. Mount a sufficiently large drive to do a full system export
2. Prepare Pro instance - set up (temporary) admin password and enter the license key
3. On OSS instance - disable garbage collection and artifact clean up in Administration→Artifactory→Advanced→Maintenance. I did this by simply adding a next year in both cron expressions.
4. On OSS instance - disable the encryption as explained on [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeactivateArtifactoryKeyEncryption) (yes, this can only be done using an W/S API call). Failure to do so will likely land you on [this problem](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-solve-the-given-final-block-not-properly-padded-error-during-artifactory-import-export/), and you would have wasted your time.
5. On OSS instance - start the full system export ("Export System") in Administration→Artifactory→Import & Export→System. Check "Output Verbose Log" and have all other checkboxes unchecked.
6. If your database is of any decent size, the page will eventually show an "Oops" error. Ignore that, and keep monitoring the export process in the logs (`artifactory-service.log`).
7. Once the export is finished, detach the drive, and attach it to the Pro instance. Mount the file system
8. On Pro instance - start the full system import ("Import System") in Administration→Artifactory→Import & Export→System. Check "Output Verbose Log" and have all other checkboxes unchecked.
9. Again, the page will either timeout with "Oops" message, or show a login screen again. Ignore that, and monitor `artifactory-service.log` for the import process. Don't touch the UI until import completes. Once completed, your user database will be whatever it was in your OSS version. For me, the import took about 220% of the export time.